# Angular 2 named router does not work if path of parent component is blank

Tags: angular, angular-router

This is my route configuration

```
{
    path: 'home',
    component: HomepageComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'enquiry',
            component: EnquiryComponent,
            outlet: 'suboutlet'
        }
    ]
}
```

This works perfectly fine with:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home', {outlets: {suboutlet: ['enquiry']}}]);
```

But if my parent path is blank like this:

```
{
    path: '', // <-- This is blank now
    component: HomepageComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'enquiry',
            component: EnquiryComponent,
            outlet: 'suboutlet'
        }
    ]
}
```

None of the below works:

```
this.router.navigate(['', {outlets: {suboutlet: ['enquiry']}}]);
this.router.navigate(['/', {outlets: {suboutlet: ['enquiry']}}]);
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {suboutlet: ['enquiry']}}]);
```

Error:
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'enquiry'

I need this router config as my nested named outlet resides in Home page component and I dont't wan't to prefix it with /home for just to get this working

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

Here is the plunker for my above code which is working

https://plnkr.co/edit/SZhu8LxHiSKNxX3JQ22N

And I don't know why below one isn't working

https://plnkr.co/edit/jvhkN77wH6ZePErwDvT3

Comment: Did you try with `'/'` instead of `''`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the post with everything I have tried

Comment: Great. Did you also try to change the `path` to `'/'`?

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with plunker

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just stumbled across the same issue.